# WebGL INVALID OPERATION insufficient buffer size

Tags: javascript, webgl, objloader

I'm trying to write a simple program in WebGL and javascript to draw a simple object from .obj files. I'm using npm's webgl-obj-loader to load the objects. As the title says I keep getting Insufficient buffer size (Edge) and index buffer too small(FF). I used gl.geterror function and I'm getting 1282 error code which means INVALID_OPERATION.

```
window.onload = function () {
            OBJ.downloadMeshes(
            {
                'dragon_vrip': 'models/dragon_vrip.obj',
                'cube2': 'models/cube2.obj'
            }, webGLStart);
}
```

This is the way I use to load obj files.

```
        app.meshes = meshes;

        OBJ.initMeshBuffers(gl, app.meshes.dragon_vrip);
        OBJ.initMeshBuffers(gl, app.meshes.cube2);

        vertArray = app.meshes.cube2.vertices.slice();
        normArray = app.meshes.cube2.vertexNormals.slice();
        indicesArray = app.meshes.cube2.indices.slice();
        texCoord = app.meshes.cube2.textures.slice();
```

```
            var myMesh=app.meshes.cube2;

            var pointsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointsBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

            var textureBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoord, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);

            var normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(2, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(2);

            var indices = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            console.log(indices.size);
```

Step two: Init of the buffers.

```
                function drawFunc() {
                    rotateAngleX += 0.01;
                    rotateAngleY += 0.02;

                    mat4.fromXRotation(rotateXMatrix, rotateAngleX);
                    mat4.fromYRotation(rotateYMatrix, rotateAngleY);
                    mat4.multiply(modelMatrix, rotateXMatrix, rotateYMatrix);

                    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLocation, false, modelMatrix);

                    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indicesArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

                    requestAnimationFrame(drawFunc);

                }
                requestAnimationFrame(drawFunc);
```

And here I'm trying to draw a simple cube.

Arrays size is: vertices:72  indices:36  texCoords:48  normals:72

Considering vertices are triplets of x,y,z points the vertex buffer contains 24 points(vertex[0]=x, vertex[1]=y, vertex[2]=z, ...), and indices array doesn't contain higher number than 23, so I don't understand where the error occurs. Also is there any way to debug the buffers? I tried spector.js but didn't help much since the draw calls do nothing because of the errors.

Comment: Can you make a working example? with obj files like this    
   ->   https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/8djzyjL3/

Comment: I used your code and shaders for my models, they worked fine. So now I suppose it is shader or camera projection since my models are not getting drawn. But at least I fixed the buffer error

Comment: ok let me post, as an answer, if you like you are welcome to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a complete example below:

```js
"use strict";

var m = ThreeDMath;

function main() {
  var cubeVertices = [-1, -1, -1,
    1, -1, -1,
    1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1,
    1, -1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1,
  ];
  var indices = [
    0, 1,
    1, 2,
    2, 3,
    3, 0,
    4, 5,
    5, 6,
    6, 7,
    7, 4,
    0, 4,
    1, 5,
    2, 6,
    3, 7,
  ];

  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    alert("no webgl");
    return;
  }

  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(
    gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var worldViewProjectionLoc =
    gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_worldViewProjection");

  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array(cubeVertices),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Uint16Array(indices),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  function render(clock) {
    clock *= 0.001;

    var scale = 4;

    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas, window.devicePixelRatio);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    var fieldOfView = Math.PI * 0.25;
    var aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    var projection = m.perspective(fieldOfView, aspect, 0.0001, 500);
    var radius = 5;
    var eye = [
      Math.sin(clock) * radius,
      1,
      Math.cos(clock) * radius,
    ];
    var target = [0, 0, 0];
    var up = [0, 1, 0];
    var view = m.lookAt(eye, target, up);

    var worldViewProjection = m.multiplyMatrix(view, projection);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(worldViewProjectionLoc, false, worldViewProjection);

    gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-lessons-helper.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/3d-math.js"></script>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec4 a_position; uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection; void main() { gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * a_position; }
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,0,1); }
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

[Working code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/8djzyjL3/)

Answer (score 2):

Ok for some reason I had to add new type of array in the bufferdata function, like this.

```
var indices = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint32Array(indicesArray),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

same goes for the rest of the buffers.